# mouseleave event with popup form

Tags: jquery

If somebody visit the website page and the they want to move from website page of body then come popup form with close button. I did as like popup is working but close button is not working.

Also if possible when I press the <kbd>esc</kbd> the popup form should close(hide).

```
<div class="popupBox"><button class="btn">x</button></div>

<style type="text/css">
    .popupBox{
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
        position: relative;
            display: none;
    }
.popupBox .btn{
        position: absolute;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        text-align: center;;
        border-radius: 100%;
        color: #000;
        top: -15px;
        right: -15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #f9f9f9;
    }
```

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/mdsa/y3Ysm/

Comment: Thanks to all.working good but in IE10, 9 is support mouseleave popup form and second Can you plz it's possible to press button 'Esc' popup form should close(hide).

Answer (score 0):

1. all event assignments have to be inside the $(function() {})
2. you had a syntactically wrong click on the mouseleave
3. You had too many } in the button assignment
4. If you have $(function() {} you may not use onload in the fiddle, instead use head
5. I changed to $(document) instead of $('html')
6. added test for <kbd>esc</kbd> - please note this will only be registered if the document has focus, so in the jsFiddle it will only work if you are back in the frame

This works

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2xbXg/)

```
$(function () {
    $(document).mouseleave(function () {
        $('.popupBox').show();
    });
    $('.btn').on('click', function () {
        $(".popupBox").hide();
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) {  // esc
         var $popup = $(".popupBox");
         if ($popup.is(":visible")) $popup.hide();
      }  
    });    
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following...I removed one extra bracket `}` in js(from your fiddle).

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nikhiln/y3Ysm/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $('html').mouseleave('click', function () {
        $('.popupBox').show();
    });
});

$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    $(".popupBox").hide();
});
```

Comment: Why are you commenting on this answer? It is still not working after just removing the }

Comment: @mplungjan apart from closing on Escp button wat's not workin? can u explain?

Comment: If popup come should we close then we have to click on close button but it is possible to just press key Esc and popup will hide it.

Comment: 1) no click on a mouseleave function, 2) your fiddle is not hiding the popup so it is not showing any action 3) you are still running onload so the $(function() {}) is not working. 4) you are not assigning the click inside the $(function() {}) - Did you test your fiddle at all? @MDSA: Did you look at my answer above? I have fixed the script and added the ESC to it

Comment: popup form should come only on one times come until refresh the page. Means one time page load. One time mouseleave should work.Again until don't refresh the page it should not work. can you plz

Comment: You did not read the question correctly. The popup should show when the user moves outside the page. Then esc or click on close should close it. You have syntax errors and are using a wrong setting in the fiddle and you do not wrap the button click event handler in the $(function() {...}). I believe I have handled all the errors and the new feature in my answer so there is not even a need for you to fix yours anymore

Comment: @mplungjan I think question was edited after my answer. Anyway you have fixed everything.

Comment: @MDSA pls refer answer from mplungjan...no need to discuss anything on this answer thread.

Comment: I did some editing. I added the ESC requirement from a comment. That is all